# How to refresh a page automatically after 3 seconds on button click - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, form, refresh

I have a form in SharePoint. People can fill out this form. Once this form is completed its go sales department.  In this form, there is a Cancel Request button that allows the user to cancel a request that is already filled in.  I found out when users click on the Cancel Request button, they have a message telling them that the request will be canceled then nothing happen after. They have to manually refresh the page each time in other to complete the process.
I would like to know how I can refresh the page automatically for 3 seconds when users click on the Cancel Button.

Comment: Should you post your current custom code ?

Answer (score 0):

Below can get you started.

```
//bind the event with button click.....
    $( "#target" ).click(function() {
// ReferchPage() will be called after 3 seconds of button click.
        setTimeout(function(){ RefreshPage(); }, 3000);
    });

// function call which will refresh page
    function RefreshPage(){
    location.reload();
    }
```

Comment: you just need to replace $( "#target" ) with your button id $( "#yourbutton id" )..... paste your html code which is getting generated for cancel button....

Comment: am using this code:  ="<a href='#' onclick=""Script.gestionItemCourant('"&NumDemand&",duplicate')"">"&" Duplicate</a>"

Comment: can i call this method setTimeout(function(){ RefreshPage(); }, 3000); , inside a presaveitem() just before the line   return true

Comment: This is the code to refresh page: <script type="text/javascript">
 
function refreshPage(){
location.reload();
}
setTimeout(refreshPage, 60000);
 
</script>


#Read more: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/05/reload-sharepoint-page-automatically-using-javascript.html#ixzz68Zi6OXnp